# Why is navigation controller not working when - (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier: is implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I need to verify credentials. So the segue is linked from first view controller to second view controller in a sign in button. 
When I do the segue without any condition check. the navigation works fine.

But when i control the segue using the code below in first view controller, navigation flow disrupts. When the criterias are met it goes to second view controller but when i try to go back to first view controller through navigation controller the screen turns black.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([userTxt.text isEqualToString:username]&&[passwordTxt.text isEqualToString:password]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signin" sender:nil];
        return YES;

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"INCORRECT" message:@" INCORRECT USER NAME OR PASSWORD" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil    , nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signin" sender:nil];
```

Comment: shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender: is called by the framework in order to know whether the segue should be run or not. If you return yes the framework will run the segue for you when the button is tapped.

Comment: I got it.So what happens when I call performSegueWithIdentifier again ?

Comment: Nothing wishful. At best it will performs the ague twice. Since you are pushing controllers on the navigation stack, it will probably try to push a second view controller while the one form the fist segue is still animating. Which is probably not too good.